# Will my luggage be checked all the way through on a Bristol → Amsterdam → Singapore → Perth itinerary?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I am flying with KLM from Bristol airport to Amsterdam and then have two connecting flights to Perth stopping in Singapore. (with Singapore airlines)
Will I have to re-check in my baggage at Amsterdam?
Also the check in details state self service check in at Bristol, is that just for the first flight? Usually for similar flights from London your checked the whole way. I'm confused because of the first flight. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you book everything on one ticket? If yes, then you will be able to check this through. Verify this with your check-in agent. If you booked this on separate tickets, then you will need to collect the baggage in Amsterdam and check it in. Note that you need to be allowed to enter the Schengen area for this. Either way, *ask the checkin agent* to be on the safe side. **Even with self-checkin, there will be an agent to collect your bags**. There are a few countries where you need to always collect your baggage, even on international transfers. The Netherlands are no such country, though.

Answer (score 3):

From my search it seems you are flying KL1050 (KLM CityHopper) from Bristol to Amsterdam; then KL0835 (Amsterdam to Changi), and then SQ215 (Changi - Perth).

This is a single ticket; so your baggage should be checked all the way through from Bristol; and you should be picking up your bags in Perth.

At the check-in desk/kiosk - you should get 3 boarding passes; and if you have bags to check you should approach the counter.

As you are transiting through Amsterdam - you may need a transit visa for the Schengen zone.

Have a safe flight - its a long one!